# Exit mulitple For loops with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `for` loops.

```
function slow() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    (function main(j) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(e).trigger("play");
        $(e).trigger("rerender");
        $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
      }, 1000 * j / 2);
    }(j));
  }
};
```

The remaining two `for` loops are the same except with speed of iteration differences.

I want to exit/break these three loops with a single jQuery click function, ie. by a click of a button with the id 'stop'.

How can I do this?

This is my [pen](http://codepen.io/furball/pen/KWmNbY)

Comment: `$('#stop').click(function() {
  
});`

Comment: `function medium() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    (function main(j) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(e).trigger("play");
        $(e).trigger("rerender");
        $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
      }, 1000 * j / 8);
    }(j));
  }
};

function fast() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
    (function main(j) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(e).trigger("play");
        $(e).trigger("rerender");
        $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
      }, 1000 * j / 16);
    }(j));
  }
};`

Comment: Which button click do you want to break teh loop?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<script>
        $(function(){

            var Break = false; // Declare this above your for loop function

            $("#btnStop").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                Break = true;
            });

            function slow() {
             for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                 if(Break){break;} // Check this for each 3 for loop
                (function main(j) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).trigger("play");
                    $(e).trigger("rerender");
                    $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
                  }, 1000 * j / 2);
                }(j));
                }

                // I'm repeating same for loop for illustration. 
                for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                 if(Break){break;} // Check this for each 3 for loop
                (function main(j) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).trigger("play");
                    $(e).trigger("rerender");
                    $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
                  }, 1000 * j / 2);
                }(j));
                }

                for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                 if(Break){break;} // Check this for each 3 for loop
                (function main(j) {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).trigger("play");
                    $(e).trigger("rerender");
                    $('#Generation').text('Generation: ' + j);
                  }, 1000 * j / 2);
                }(j));
                }
            };
        })
    </script>
```